# Accessing a PHP session variable in jQuery file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I have 2 files. A PHP file that sets a session variable and a Jquery(.js) file that needs to access that session variable. But Javascript is client sided and PHP is server sided so how would I be able to create a javascript variable that has the value of that PHP session variable(assuming it's a string).

The following doesn't work(because it has to be in the same page I think):

```
var php_var = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could get it with AJAX.

Comment: Your code could work but you should use `var php_var = <?php echo json_encode($php_var); ?>;` to make sure everything gets encoded correctly. Apart from that your code needs more context, is this part of a php file or a javascript file, is this loaded or can it be loaded at page load, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a PHP file (foo.php) which contains the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'foo';

echo $_SESSION['foo'];
?>
```

You could use jQuery to get the value:

```
$.get('foo.php', function(data) {
    var foo = data; // 'foo' in this case
});
```

I am using the `$.get` AJAX shortcut method but you could also go with any of the other jQuery AJAX methods.

Comment: Although this is certainly not wrong, I wonder if ajax is really needed. The OP's code could work as well depending on the context. At least from the limited information in the question that I can see...

Comment: Agreed @jeroen. My only clue the OP might need AJAX was this statement, *"The following doesn't work(because it has to be in the same page I think):"*

Comment: look at the OP question he is directly trying to echo the php variable so he does not really need ajax call as per looking at the code.

Comment: That is why I said the OP *"could"* use jQuery @Sourabh, it wasn't an absolute.